# Setting emacs window gobal keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, window

I have emacs in full-screen running through the terminal and split into 4 equally sized windows. Instead of using `C-x o` to go to the other window I would like to hardcode commands for going to each window.

Perhaps I could make the commands as follows:

1. `C-w C-i` -- upper left window
2. `C-w C-o` -- upper right window
3. `C-w C-k` -- lower left window
4. `C-w C-l` -- lower right window
5. What can I add to my `~/.emacs` file to set 4 global-key commands to switch between all 4 screens as demonstrated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a simple function like that and set key bindings.

```
(defun select-nth-window (n)
  "Focus Nth window"
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-selected-window (selected-frame)
                 (frame-first-window))
  (set-frame-selected-window (selected-frame)
                 (nth n (window-list))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-w C-i") '(lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (select-nth-window 0)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w C-o") '(lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (select-nth-window 2)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w C-k") '(lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (select-nth-window 1)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w C-l") '(lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (select-nth-window 3)))
```

**Edit:**
I don't know how to save window layout but [Emacs Wiki: Session Management](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement) may help you.

You also could learn more about emacs lisp from [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/) and [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html).

Comment: What can I add to my `.emacs` file to start emacs with 4 windows like this? Also, where do you acquire the knowledge to find these functions?